# Serializing/deserializing binary tree in most space-efficient way

Tags: java, optimization, tree, serialization

I'm looking for corrections, optimizations, general code review, etc.

```
final class TreeData<T> {
    private T item;
    private boolean left;
    private boolean right;

    public TreeData(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public T getData () {
        return item;
    }

    public boolean getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(boolean left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public boolean getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(boolean right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf () {
        return !left && !right;
    }   
}



/**
 * There are 2 common approaches over the internet:
 * 
 * 1. Preorder deserialization.
 *    Cost: (2 * nodeSize * (n + 1))
 * 
 * 2. PreOrder and Inorder deserialization
 *    Cost: (2 * nodeSize * (n))
 * 
 * 3. Object based  (wrap node inside an object, with a boolean
 *    Cost: (1 * (nodeSize + boolean + 8(object overhead)) * n )
 * 
 * The third option triumphs iff:
 * (nodeSize + boolean + 8) < (2 * nodeSize)
 * boolean + 8  < nodeSize
 * 1       + 8  < nodeSize
 * 
 * When a node is saves as an Integer, then the nodeSize is (4 + 8 => 12)
 * So 
 * 9  < 12.
 * Thus works :)
 * 
 * OR:
 * 
 * Simply consider a single tree with 1 node, of type Int.
 * Pre + Inorder is     = 2 * (8(int object) + 4(actual value)) * 1 => 24
 * Object with boolean  = 1 * (8(wrapper object) + 12(int object) +  2) * 1 =>  22.
 * 
 * 
 * Complexity: O(n)
 *
 */
public final class SerializeDeserializeBinarytree<T> {

    TreeNode<T> root;

    public SerializeDeserializeBinarytree(List<T> items) {
        if (items == null) throw new NullPointerException("the items cannot be null");
        create(items);
    }

     /** construction using parent child relation that left child is 2i + 1 and right is 2i + 2 */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void create (List<T> items) {
        assert items != null;

        root = new TreeNode<T>(null, items.get(0), null);

        final Queue<TreeNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = items.size() / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                final TreeNode<T> current = queue.poll();
                final int left = 2 * i + 1;
                final int right = 2 * i + 2;

                if (items.get(left) != null) {
                    current.left = new TreeNode<T>(null, items.get(left), null);
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                    current.right = new TreeNode<T>(null, items.get(right), null);
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class TreeNode<T> {
        TreeNode<T> left;
        T item;
        TreeNode<T> right;

        TreeNode (TreeNode<T> left, T item,  TreeNode<T> right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.item = item;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

    public List<TreeData<T>> serialize () {
        if (root == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The root should be non-null");
        }
        List<TreeData<T>> objectList = new ArrayList<TreeData<T>>(countNodes(root));
        preorderSerialize(root, objectList);
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(objectList);
    }

    private int countNodes(TreeNode<T> root) {
        assert root != null;
        if (root != null) {
            return countNodes(root.left) + countNodes(root.right) + 1;  
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private boolean preorderSerialize(TreeNode<T> node, List<TreeData<T>> objectList ) {
        assert root != null;
        assert objectList != null;

        if (node != null) {
            TreeData<T> treeData = new TreeData<T>(node.item);
            objectList.add(treeData);

            treeData.setLeft(preorderSerialize (node.left, objectList));
            treeData.setRight(preorderSerialize (node.right, objectList));

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private class CounterContainer {
        private int counterContainer;

        public CounterContainer(int counterContainer) {
            this.counterContainer = counterContainer;
        }

        public void increment() {
            counterContainer++;
        }

        public int getCounter () {
            return counterContainer;
        }
    }

    public void deserialize (List<TreeData<T>> treeDatas) {
        if (treeDatas == null) throw new NullPointerException("The treeData should not be null");
        root = preOrderDeserialize (treeDatas, new CounterContainer(0));
    }

    private TreeNode<T> preOrderDeserialize (List<TreeData<T>> treeDatas, CounterContainer cc) {
        assert treeDatas != null;
        assert cc != null;

        TreeData<T> treeData = treeDatas.get(cc.getCounter());
        TreeNode<T> node = new TreeNode<T>(null, treeData.getData(), null);

        if (treeData.isLeaf()) return node;

        if (treeData.getLeft()) {
            cc.increment();
            node.left = preOrderDeserialize(treeDatas, cc);
        }
        if (treeData.getRight()) {
            cc.increment();
            node.right = preOrderDeserialize(treeDatas, cc);
        } 
        return node;
    }

    public List<T> preOrderIterator () {
        final List<T> preOrderList = new ArrayList<T>();
        if (root == null) throw new NoSuchElementException("The root should be non-null");
        preOrder(root, preOrderList);
        return preOrderList;
    }

    private void preOrder (TreeNode<T> node, List<T> preOrderList) {
        assert preOrderList != null;

        if (node != null) {
            preOrderList.add(node.item);
            preOrder(node.left, preOrderList);
            preOrder(node.right, preOrderList);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         /**
            *       1
            *     2   3
            *   4  n 6  n 
            */
        Integer[] arr2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, null, 6 };

        SerializeDeserializeBinarytree<Integer> sdbt = new SerializeDeserializeBinarytree<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr2));
        for (TreeData<Integer> treeData : sdbt.serialize()) {
            System.out.print(treeData.getData() + ":");
        }

        System.out.println();

        sdbt.deserialize(sdbt.serialize());
        for (Integer node : sdbt.preOrderIterator()) {
            System.out.print(node + ":");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Serialization" usually means to turn an object into a machine-readable string representation or byte stream. Do you mean "traversal" and "reconstruction"?

Comment: Yes, well, my code is one step short of it. my missing step would be to use object output stream to convert list into byte stream

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to serialize the tree, then you want to repeatedly append node representations to a `StringBuilder` or write them to an `OutputStream`.  For space efficiency, it would be better to do so a node at a time, rather than to build up the entire list.

Therefore, instead of using a `List<TreeData<T>>` as the intermediate data structure, you should create an `PreOrderIterator<TreeData<T>>`, `InOrderIterator<TreeData<T>>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A minor bug: You get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for an empty list in `SerializeDeserializeBinarytree.create(List<T> items)`. You don't have a comment stating you need to input a list containing at least something. Consider returning `IllegalArgumentException` and adding a comment.